# Как отформатировать данные, получаемые из json-файла, и отправить их телеграмм боту?

Tags: python, json, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Данные сохраняются в json-файл (title, salary, link).
Далее нужно, чтобы эти данные доставались из этого файла и отправлялись боту.
Python, aiogram.

Сообщение (пример):

```
Программист 
Зарплата: 100 000
Ссылка: *ссылка*
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял вопрос, требуется открыть и распарсить json, а затем подставить нужные значения в сообщение бота.

Открываем json:

```py
def open_file():
    with open(my_file, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    return data
```

Обрабатываем данные:

```
async def add_message(message: types.Message) -> None:
    data = open_file()
    #работам с открытым json как со словарем
    for key, value in data.items():
        #если требуется подставить ключ
        title = key["title"]
        #если требуется подставить значение
        salary = value["salary"]
        link = value["link"]
    await message.answer(f"{title}\n"
                         f"Зарплата: {salary}"
                         f"Ссылка: {link}")
```

Comment: Не забудете сделать
import json